# VBA - problem copying data from storage array to sheet array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, copy

I am trying to replicate what a Data Table does in excel in VBA. I have got the code working as I want thus far however when I copy data out of the temporary storage array it is offset by 1 Column and 1 Row.

I cannot figure out what the issue is? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub DataTableLoop()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CodeRng As Range
Dim PasteRng As Range
Dim WatchRng As Range
Dim ResultRng As Range
Dim ResultRes As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim TempArr As Variant
Dim CodeVar As Range

Set CodeRng = Worksheets("OptionCodes").[CodeTop]
Set PasteRng = Worksheets("OptionCodes").[OptionsCode]
Set WatchRng = Worksheets("OptionCodes").[WatchRange]
Set ResultRng = Worksheets("OptionCodes").[ResultsRange]

col = WatchRng.Columns.Count

x = Worksheets("OptionCodes").[Iterations].Value
y = x - 1
i = 0

Set ResultRes = ResultRng.Resize(x)

ReDim MyArray(x, col)

Do While i <= y

Set CodeVar = CodeRng.Offset(i, 0)

Count = i + 1

Application.StatusBar = "Iteration: " & Count & " of " & x

    CodeVar.Copy
    PasteRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Application.Calculate
    
    TempArr = WatchRng
    For j = 1 To col
        MyArray(Count, j) = TempArr(1, j)
    Next j
    
i = i + 1

Loop

ResultRes = MyArray

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redim` is by default 0 based, so your array is actually 1 row and column larger than you expect. To get 1 based you need to specify the lower bounds

```
ReDim MyArray(1 To x, 1 To col)
```